# What is the equivalent of 'SELECT * INTO' in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, odata

I am building a `SSIS package` in which package i need to transfer from 
an `odata source` some tables into `sql server`.

So far i have implement an "insert into" query to the `sql server` from the tables i read from `odata Source`. Because the number of tables are 10+ is there a way that i can do "select into" query for faster transfer of those tables in `SSIS` ?

Comment: If you are looking at temporary tables, consider loading into an ADO object (recordset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS has no build in operation to create a table on a destination based on a data set, which is what `SELECT ... INTO` does.

There is no easy tweak to do this either, SSIS is mostly based for static metadata ETLs, that is performing operations between different sources and destinations with consistent structures and data types. You might achieve what you need with custom scripts, but that would be as well completely outside of SSIS.

If you already know the data you will be inserting into, create the destination tables  first (with `CREATE TABLE`) and then use SSIS to map the corresponding columns. If your destination tables will be dynamic then you will have a hard time using regular SSIS operations to match the metadata of each table, since this is set at design time.

If the problem isn't the table's column data type but the speed of the operation (`SELECT ... INTO` has minimal logging), then the fastest option is using the **bulk insert** operation on the destination component when working with SQL Server. It will be faster than regular inserts, but usually slower than performing a `SELECT ... INTO` directly from SQL.

Comment: Thank you for response...i found it really annoying for not be able to do a simple "select into"

Comment: Can someone please explain me why we shouldnt create a simple "sql into" script and have SSIS to run as sql task or sql script?
source and dest are both sql server databases on same instance.

Comment: @atalaycelebi you can, but in that case you will be using SSIS just as a means to execute an sql script. In that case you may avoid SSIS altogether and use SQL Server Agent or any client that can connect to SQL Server and execute SQL. The main purpose of SSIS is to design data flows to transfer data across databases and connections (hence "Integration Services" from the name), which isn't the case here.

Comment: @EzLo with all due respect, what you say kind of means that I should avoid doing just to sake to utilize the SSIS. I am aware of what you are saying. I am merely asking what is the advantage? If for instance, I plan to transfer data from one DB to another which sit in same instance, why would not i do the way I mentioned or the way  you mentioned?

Comment: Just because I find it simpler to avoid SSIS in that particular case; you have to install SSIS on the server running the package, configure it's connections and then use the client to execute the package. If it's practical to you then by all means you can use it. A good thing is that if someday you want to start logging times or doing other operations, you already have the DTS package configured. If you need to execute multiple scripts that depend on each other then SSIS is actually very good.